Google ADCs don't seem to work using Python on Windows 11 / Gcloud SDK 475.0.0
So just migrated from a Windows 10 to Windows 11 machine and notice Python scripts don't seem to be picking up Google ADCs.  I'm repeatedly getting this error:
Reauthentication is needed. Please run 'gcloud auth application-default login' to reauthenticate.
Python code uses google-auth, and is failing on the credentials.refresh() step in this code:
import google.auth
import google.auth.transport.requests

SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read-only"]

credentials, project_id = google.auth.default(scopes=SCOPES, quota_project_id=None)
_ = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
credentials.refresh(_)

I am noticing that C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\application_default_credentials.json is getting updated upon logging in, and Terraform authenticates without issue.
The same code works without issue on Mac and Linux.

Are you sure you are using the Google cloud python library and not the Google apis python client library. I will test this in the morning if I remember

Why are you including this parameter quota_project_id=None?

Was able to fix by un-installing Docker desktop, then in-installing gcloud

When posting an answer explain why this worked.  Docker and the Google Cloud CLI do not interact with each other. Something else is going on. If you do not want to provide additional information, delete the question.
